# Fluid Simulation does not follow collision object morphing with skape keys

Tags: fluid-simulation, shape-keys

I have an ice cube in my scene that is melting. I want a slow melt so didn't want to use fluid to geometry. So I have my ice cube with a flow object ontop of it acting as the water dripping from the cube. The cube melts by using shape keys. I have used sculping to replicate the ice shrinking. Animating the shape key number value, making the ice cube shrink as the water runs down it.
However the water flow effector only follows the first shape, even though the mesh is being "compressed".
How do I replicate this, do I apply scale to the animation in each time the shape changes? Is there something I need to change?
I have attached images of my work flow below.
[image]

[image: Fluid Following First Object Shape]

[image: Fluid Not Following Object With Animated Shape Keys]
[image: Ice Cube Collision Object Settings]
[image: Shape Key Settings]

Comment: Did you bake the fluid simulation before you animated the cube shrinking?

Comment: Yes I did, I figured out the solution I'm going to post the answer now

Answer (score 1):

So to correct this issue, I applied a scale keyframe at each start frame and end frame of the shape key. i.e. from 0-1.0 of the shape key key frame. Once all my shape keys and scale key frames were in place I baked the fluid simulation.